# Search keys using regexp in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Below is my document and I want to search values "availability" using regular expressions like this:

```
"regexp" : { 
    "availability": {
    "value": "2014-*-10"
    }
}
```

My document:

```
{
   "_index": "testing",
   "_type": "test",
   "_id": "1",
   "_version": 1,
   "exists": true,
   "_source": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Test",
      "availability": {
         "2014-02-15": {
            ["1", "2"]
         },
         "2014-02-14": {
            ["1", "2", "3"]
         },
         "2014-03-15": {
            ["1"]
         },
         "2014-03-14": {
            ["1", "2", "3"]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

How can I search for keys as it works (regex) for normal values (not arrays)?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by regex? it does not make sense to use regular expressions in elasticsearch anyways.

Comment: I need to search all documents that match ["availability"]["2014-*-15"] as there can be a lot more of them. Would that help you?

Comment: @phoet you should maybe read some [doco](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html)

Comment: @mconlin you are right, i did not use that one before. thx for pointing out.

Comment: @mconlin i loled http://bit.ly/KBN53R

Comment: Cant you read guys? Its about searching key (field name) not a value of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use "default_field" with * wildcard like this or similar combination:

```
{
   "query" : {
        "query_string": {
            "default_field": "availability.2014-*-13.*",
            "query": "1"
        }

    }
}
```